# ffmpeg downloading parts of Youtube videos but for some of them they have a black screen for a few seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

So im using ffmpeg to download some youtube videos with specific start and stop times. My code looks like `os.system("ffmpeg -i $(youtube-dl --no-check-certificate -f 18 --get-url %s) -ss %s -to %s -c:v copy -c:a copy %s"% (l, y, z, w))` where the variables would all be the name of the file, the url, and the start and stop times. Some of the vidoes come out just fine, others have a black screen and only a portion of the video, and a very few amount have just audio files. My time is formated as x.y where x would be the seconds and y would be the milliseconds. Is this the issue so I need to transform it to 00:00:00.0 format? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system("ffmpeg -ss %s -i $(youtube-dl --no-check-certificate -f 18 --get-url %s)  -t %s -c:v copy -c:a copy %s"% (l, y, z, w))
```

- -ss start the video with 00:00:00.0000 format
- -t the duration of scene in seconds

example if you want to extract a scene from second 30, and a duration of 3 seconds

```
os.system("ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30.0000 -i $(youtube-dl --no-check-certificate -f 18 --get-url %s)  -t 3 -c:v copy -c:a copy %s"% (l, y, z, w))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with Python :)
Add `'-c:a', 'copy',`to ffmpeg command line (part) helps out with the black picture / frames / screen in the video.

```
def ydl_info():
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo[height<=720][tbr>1][filesize>0.05M]',
        'outtmpl': '%(id)s.%(ext)s', # Template for output names.
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(
            'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZhWTjnIn78',
            download=False # False for just extract the info
        )
    return info


def ffmpeg_cut():
    info = ydl_info()

    URL    = info['formats'][-1]['url'] # media_url # If there are several media formats then to get media url for the last format:
    START  = args.start_time
    END    = '00:00:03.00'
    OUTPUT = os.path.join(args.output, args.name+args.format)
    print('Output:', OUTPUT)

    #ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15.00 -i "OUTPUT-OF-FIRST URL" -t 00:00:10.00 -c copy out.mp4
    #cmd = "ffmpeg -ss {} -i {} -t {} -c copy {}".format(START, URL, END, OUTPUT)
    subprocess.call([
        'ffmpeg',
        '-i',  URL,
        '-ss', START,
        '-t',  END,
        '-c:a', 'copy', OUTPUT, # '-c:v' copies only video and '-c:a' only audio
    ])
    return None
```